# How small do you need to compress mass to make a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, mass, event-horizon

I am wondering if there is an equation for how close you need to compress a mass to make a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole). I have seen claims that if the earth is shrunk to the size of a golf ball, it would create a black hole. However, I can't find any equations for this size online. Ideally, the equation would take into account the spin and electric charge of the black hole as well.

Comment: Look up [Schwarzschild radius](https://www.britannica.com/science/Schwarzschild-radius)

Comment: Alternative source of Schwarzschild radius. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius

Comment: I think this is too general. If  you have enough mass to begin with then it is inevitable that something will become a black hole eventually, whatever its initial radius, The answer is not "the Schwarzschild radius". Also, how would the collapse of something like the Earth create a charged black hole? I think you should drop that requirement. And, if you are talking about spinning black holes, then what is the angula rmomentum of the mass and does it lose angular momentum in any way as it collapses?

Comment: How can you say you didn't find any equations online if  the article you yourself linked contains all the equations you need, is this supposed to be a joke?

Comment: I didn't put that link in, it was edited in. Thank you to whoever did that

Comment: The proper value of the Schwarzschild radius was given by Karl Schwarzschild himself in his original paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9905030 where $r\equiv\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=0$ at the horizon for a black hole of any size. This is evident from the definition of $r$ on p. $2$ and the final solution, formula $(14)$, where $\alpha$ denotes the reduced circumference of the horizon commonly referred to as the "Schwarzschild radius" $r_s\equiv\alpha$. So you'd need to compress mass to a zero size to create a black hole.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with any constant positive density material, and accumulate a big enough ball, and it will become a black hole, without any need for compression. A black hole is a lot of material in a small space, but what constitutes "small space" eventually increases with mass faster than linearly.

Comment: _it will become a black hole, without any need for compression_ Really ? Then why Schwarzschild radius is needed for ? Not for compression of given $M$ into $r$ ? Similarly, according to you, any big enough star can become a black hole **without** a collapse (compression) ? This is very wrong. Schwarzschild radius shows that exactly you need to pass some density threshold to become a black hole. And for that you need compression in one way or another.

Comment: the threshold is not density. wiki link above shows some neutron stars denser than some black holes. it is just more complicated than you think

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas The Schwarzschild radius of a ball of any incompressible material is proportional to the balls’s mass and thus the cube of the ball’s radius $a$. For large enough $a$, the Schwarzschild radius will therefore exceed the actual radius, because $a^3$ grows faster than $a$.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the OP's question though -- they're asking "given a certain amount of material, how densely packed does that material have to be to form a black hole". The answer to that is given by the Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: Well, seems we both are right to some degree. There's a couple of useful formulas in [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius). So you can go in two ways for forming a black hole, you need either to shrink given mass $M$ to a specific radius or given object _constant_ density $\rho$ - grow it to some extra radius. For Earth, shrinking it gives $9 mm$ radius black hole, and for growing it - gives another black hole of $\approx 1 AU$ in radius. But... as there can't be two different versions of Schwarzschild radius, second way must involve collapse of material.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas No. Except once a black hole forms the growing mass has to collapse. It doesn't have to collapse to form the black hole.

Comment: @EricSmith A question like this wil always get the obvious standard answer. I do not have to be the one to bring that up. But there will always be people like AgniusVasiliauskas who would not have seen the case I was talking about. That is the more instructional thing to cover. Not to mention that, to understand my answer, one must first understand Schwarzchild radius concept, and that means that they would also get their question answered for free.